# C++ alignment of class - member call on misaligned address

Tags: c++, alignment

I'm using UBSAN and am getting the following error. Note that I'm compiling with clang 6.0.1 with -fsanitize=undefined. I've read a number of background questions on SO and still can't solve my particular issue. Here are the background questions for reference:

- [What is the recommended way to align memory in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791428/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-align-memory-in-c11)
- [Misaligned address using virtual inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46474238/misaligned-address-using-virtual-inheritance)

  runtime error: member call on misaligned address 0x000001f67230 for type 'const A *', which requires 64 byte alignment
  0x000001f67230: note: pointer points here
   00 00 00 00  c0 72 f6 01 00 00 00 00  08 00 00 00 00 02 00 00  40 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00

Here are some things to note about class C:

- the object of type C is created using `new` (`C* o = new C();`)
- type C has a member of type A that has 64 byte alignment. I verified this using alignof.
- C is declared using `class alignas(64) C` -- but that doesn't solve my problem

My current hypothesis is that I need to use the C++11 equivalent of the C++17 `std::aligned_alloc` to create the object using aligned storage. But, I'm not sure how to best do this or if it will actually solve my problem. I would prefer to solve the problem once in the definition of class C as opposed to every time I create a C, if possible. What is the recommended approach to solve this issue to remove the UBSAN error?

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track, extended alignment is generally implementation-defined and may require some hand-holding. Even C++17's extended alignment support is ultimately implementation defined, and you implementation may or may not call `aligned_alloc` for 64. (What's new in C++17 is that your implementation *may* now call `aligned_alloc`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class already has a member that requires 64 Byte alignment, then the class will already also have 64 Byte alignment out of necessity. So adding an explicit `alignas(64)` is not really gonna change anything.

The basic problem here is that allocation functions (in C++11) [are only required](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.stc.dynamic.allocation#2) to return memory aligned to [fundamental alignment](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.align#2). C++11 left it implementation-defined whether over-aligned types are supported by new or not [[expr.new]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.new#1). C++17 [introduced](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/align_val_t) new-extended alignment and additional allocation functions to deal with that (if and which new-extended alignments are supported, however, is still implementation-defined).

If you can switch to a compiler that supports C++17, chances are that your code will just work. Otherwise you will probably have to either use some implementation-specific function to allocate aligned memory or just roll your own solution, e.g., based on [std::align](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align) and placement new (which would work in C++11 too)…

Comment: Thanks. A couple questions: 1) I'm using clang 6, so I can specify a different standard `-std=c++17`. Are you saying that may just work without changing the code?

Comment: 2) I typically create aligned dynamically allocated memory in  c++11 using posix_memalign. Would that, plus placement-new, be the recommended c++11 approach to solve this?

Comment: @Kulluk007 I didn't test it, so I'm not sure; but it could be worth a try. If it doesn't work, you can resort to just using `posix_memalign` if a non-portable solution is sufficient for your needs. You could overload the operator new/delete functions for this particular type to use `posix_memalign` under the hood so that everything works just as it normally would and you don't have to orchestrate the correct allocation manually every time you instantiate such an object via new. That should also allow `unique_ptr` etc. to work just as usual…

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get the UBSAN errors to go away by switching to C++14 and using posix_memalign and placement-new. I wasn't able to upgrade to C++17 yet because of some macOS libs I'm currently relying on. However, I'm getting a possibly innocuous warning from ASAN now about mismatch between malloc and delete because I'm malloc'ing the buffer and then using placement new, but calling delete on the created object. I'm not calling free on the buffer because delete should also delete the malloced buffer (right?). Is my understanding correct that the ASAN alloc-dealloc-mismatch is innocuous?

Comment: @Kulluk007 No, your understanding is not correct. You cannot use `delete` to free memory that was allocated with `malloc()`. You have to use `free()`.

Comment: Ok thanks. The issue is that I need to call the destructor of the object that is created using placement new (it does a variety of other cleanups). When I tried to call BOTH free of the raw buffer that is used as well as delete on the object, I get `malloc: *** error for object 0x7f996ad09300: pointer being freed was not allocated`  I tried putting the free both before and after the delete. When I remove the delete call the error goes away -- but of course I don't get the other benefits of my destructor. What's the recommended approch here?

Comment: @Kulluk007 When you construct an object via placement new, you have to call the destructor manually: `myobj.~MyClass();`